# Can't see rig in pose mode (blender 3.4)

Tags: rigging, pose-mode, rigidbody

I am very new to Blender and rig animation. I have downloaded [this model](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/3d-free-red-hair-woman-game-ready-1892501) and select the rig object (the one with orange human icon) and change to pose mode. However, there is no rig (the circle/square around the character for you to change limbs position) for me to select. I did alt + h but still no help, don't know I miss something, or this model doesn't have that. Can someone help me check it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry but that model requires you to register and login to download it.

Comment: You cannot expect people to help you by downloading content that you have to register for - it's a free model, but still it's not everyone's wish to register everywhere where people download models they have problems with. You could at least try to show some information on the model with screenshots of your Blender scene, the model, the outliner for example. The pictures on the download page have no usable information on how the model looks/works in Blender.

Answer (score 0):

While this model has been setup with an armature, it hasn't been rigged for easy animation.

Adding a skeleton is the first part of rigging while using inverse kinematics, constraints, drivers and custom shapes for intuitive control of your character is the rest.

If you're serious about rigging and animation I would take the time to learn it properly. For this, I can't recommend Pierrick Picaut's tutorials enough. They're paid for but worth every penny.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kNLgpc2mlA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6lYYgLKH04